# tortoiseHG suddenly fails with "Unable to remove file xxx permission denied"

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have about 50 modified files. I tried to shelve them. About halfway through, tortoiseHG says 'Unable to remove file x/y/z/foo.java, permission denied'. I tried several of the remaining files, and they all seem to have the same issue.

I've been using tortoiseHG for a long time on this Windows machine without issues. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? The files are not locked (open by another program). And they're all in the same local directory that I have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The error message is misleading. The problem was a leftover .hg/wlock file. Probably from when it initially failed doing 1/2 of the original shelving.

Deleting .hg/wlock solved the problem.